When I add FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, a gap occurs after statusbar, making the content move a little down
I am trying to make statusbar and navigation bar fully transparent, in order to do this, I add:
val w = getWindow()
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
}

inside onCreate. This makes both of them transparent. But, when I add this FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, a gap occurs after statusbar, maybe at te height of status bar, making the content move a little down. I tried also this in styles:
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item> <!-- again extends the statusbar and makes navbar translucent, not fully transparent -->
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/transparent</item>

How can I handle this?
